# Sumar elementos de un Array en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-7

Tengo un array el cual deseo sumar sus elementos pero con el algoritmo que tengo me da error.

```
var numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], suma = 0;
    forEach (numeros, function(numero){
        suma += numero;
    });
    console.log(suma);
```

Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: forEach is not defined

¿Cual es la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Y como sería haciendo un For

```
for(var i = 0; i <= numeros.length; i++){
        numero = numeros[i];
        suma += numero;
    }
```

Para comparar ambos métodos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu error esta en que la sintaxis debe ser así `arreglo.forEach()` es decir el arreglo a través del nombre de la variable que lo contiene debe acceder con la sintaxis de punto `.` al método `forEach()` y entonces quitar el nombre del arreglo que pusiste dentro del bucle; quedando así

```
var numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], suma = 0;
    numeros.forEach (function(numero){
        suma += numero;
    });
    console.log(suma);
```

Comment: Y como sería con for para comparlo edite el hilo principal

Comment: El `forEach` es bastante innecesario. Usando `Array#reduce` te permite hacerlo en una línea. Ver respuesta de @Bryro.

Comment: lo se @migudev yo solo me limite a responder a la duda expuesta, coincido contigo en lo expuesto pero la pregunta solo estaba orientada al error de sintaxis no en cual utilizar(al menos antes de la edición de la misma)

Answer (score 28):

puedes hacerlo asi:

> **nota:** la funcion Each o bucle esta descontinuada. se remplazo por `for(let i in array)` y `for(let i of array)` pero aun se mantiene el `array.prototype.forEach`

**con reduce:**

```js
let numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let total = numeros.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

console.log(total);
```

**con array.prototype.forEach**:

```js
let total=0,numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
numeros.forEach(function(a){total += a;});
console.log(total);
```

**con for of :**

```js
let total=0,numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for(let i of numeros) total+=i;
console.log(total);
```

**for clasico:**

```js
let total=0,numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for(let i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) total+=numeros[i];
console.log(total);
```

Comment: Aunque esto puede resolver el problema expuesto en la pregunta, las publicaciones que son solo código se consideran de baja calidad. Por favor, lee [answer] y edita tu respuesta para añadir más detalles sobre qué hace el código o cómo resuelve el problema.

Comment: Veo que el `foreach` es innecesario el reduce es la mejor opción, gracias

Comment: me causa curiosidad tu edición, me indicas por favor donde puedo consultar que `forEach` esta descontinuado?

Comment: Si no me equivoco, forEach no ha sido descontinuada. Es la sintaxis for each in la que sí lo ha sido.

Comment: Array.prototype.forEach sobrevive y está contemplado en el último borrador de [Ecma](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.foreach)