# ¿Cómo podría sumar todos los números de un array en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Intenté sumar varios números que se encuentran en un array, creo que lo hice mal, me gustaría que me ayudaran.

```js
let numbers = ["101", "3"];
let total = numbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

message.channel.send(total)
```

Lo que me gustaría es que diera como resultado:

104

Pero no, realmente me devuelve:
01013

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Sumar elementos de un Array en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/248429/sumar-elementos-de-un-array-en-javascript)

Answer (score 12):

Tu código es correcto, lo que ocurre es:

- Los elementos de tu vector estan *entrecomillados* lo cual provoca se interpreten como *strings*
- Al ser leidos como cadenas de texto la suma será un realidad una concatenación
- Puedes hacer un *cast* de los valores dentro del ciclo por medio del [objeto **`Number`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number)

Quedando así:

```js
    let numbers = ["101", "3"];
    let total = numbers.reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b), 0);
    
    console.log(total)
```

Agregando las observaciones de [Marcos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/16597/marcos):

La estructura de la función reductora ya cuenta con lo siguiente:

- Un acumulador (que es la variable a)
- Un valor actual (que implica a la variable b)
- El acumulador esta siendo inicializado en 0, por tanto la primer recomendación de hacer *cast* a ambas variables es redundante; *alcanza con solo aplicar dicho procedimiento a la variable b*

Entonces en el método `reduce` puede quedar así:

```
((a, b) => a + Number(b), 0);
```

Comment: Hay que ser justos, tienes una respuesta corta pero aclara muy bien las dudas del `OP` y es simple de entender, tienes mi voto arriba.

Answer (score 7):

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```js
const message = {
  channel: {
    send: (total)=>{
      console.log("Sending: " + total + "...");
    }
  }
}

let numbers = ["101", "3"];
let total = numbers.reduce((a, b) => (a | 0) + (b | 0));

message.channel.send(total)
```

No le pongas cuidado a `message` ya que es solo una simulacion de la variable `message` y su comportamiento que tienes en tu codigo real.

lo que si te debo explicar es esta parte de aca:

```
let total = numbers.reduce((a, b) => (a | 0) + (b | 0));
```

Lo que hice fue usar el operador binario `|` para forzar a `a` y a `b` a que se convirtieran en numeros enteros, (esto es lo que ocurre al hacer `a | 0` o `b | 0`) y se conoce como `pipe`.

Por lo tanto es el equivalente a transformar esas cadenas de texto en enteros de forma corta para posteriormente hacer la operacion.

**Nota: le quite el segundo parametro, no era necesario puesto que iniciabas desde el 0 siempre.**

en caso de que tambien quieras mantener digitos flotantes si lo hay `NO` deberias usar el `pipe`, puesto que solo sirve para convertir esas cadenas a `numeros enteros`.

En su lugar usa `parseFloat` si necesitas decimales:

```
let total = numbers.reduce((a, b) => parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b));
```

Espero poder haber aclarado bien tus dudas...

Answer (score 3):

Un truco que les fató es el uso del **`operador de bits not (~)`**, cuando lo usas dos veces te convierte una cadena a entero.

```js
let numbers = ["101", "3"];
let total = numbers.reduce((a, b) => ~~a + ~~b, 0);
console.log(total)
console.log(~~"-2")
```

Comment: Esta respuesta esta interesante, no se me habria ocurrido usar ese operador nunca aqui, buena respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Pueden haber muchas maneras, una es agregando un `+` para convertir el string a número, otra es quitando las comillas dobles, o usando `eval`.

#### Agregando un `+` a la izquierda

Se agrega un `+` a la izquierda de la variable que se quiere convertir de string a número, en este caso `b`.

```
a + + b
```

Código:

```js
var numbers = ["101", "3"]
var total = numbers.reduce((a, b) => a + + b, 0)
console.log(total)
```

#### Quitando comillas

Se quitan las comillas, además lo hace más legible.

```
[101, 3]
```

Código:

```js
var numbers = [101, 3]
var total = numbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
console.log(total)
```

#### Usando `eval`:

Se usa `eval` concatenando con el `+`, esto convierte un string a código *JavaScript* para evaluarlo.

```
var numbers = "  101    3  "
```

Es posible agregar los números de manera desprolija, con muchos espacios, luego procesar eso quitando los espacios mediante una expresión regular. Esto puede servir si se trabaja de manera apurada y se quiere saber el resultado lo antes posible.

Si se quiere, se pueden usar múltiples líneas, mediante *template strings*, que se usan con la comilla invertida `` ` ``

```
var numbers = `  101 
   3  
`
```

Código:

```js
var numbers = `  101 
   3  
`
var total = eval(numbers.match(/\d+/g).join("+"))
console.log(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hazlo de esta forma:

```
let total = 0;
numbers.forEach(number => total += number);
message.channel.send(total);
```

Comment: las respuestas que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad y no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Por favor, edita tu respuesta para añadir algo más de información: ¿qué hace ese código? ¿cómo soluciona el problema? ¿dónde iría en el código/proyecto de la pregunta? Lee sobre [answer] para más detalles y recomendaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Una observacion

Cuando estas manejando enteros, no los declaras con comillas (" ") van de manera normal, ya que lo interpretan como texto.

```js
    let total=0,
    numbers = [101, 3];
    for(let i of numbers) total+=i;
    console.log(total);
```

Prueba con este código a ver si funciona. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Cómo se haría si obligatoriamente los números tiene que ser strings?