# verificar si la suma de un arreglo es igual a un entero (n)

Tags: javascript, array

tengo una función que recibe un **array** y un numero **entero (n)**. Quiero verificar si la suma de cualesquiera de los números contenidos en el array es igual al numero (n) recibido en dicha función.
Devolver true o false, dependiendo el resultado.
Ej
// sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 13)  debería devolver true ya que 2 + 11 = 13

He intentado esto, pero no se porque motivo el valor de "sum" se incrementa de a 2. y no va incrementandose a partir de los nros del arreglo. Alguien puede ayudarme a saber el motivo?

```js
function sumArray(array, n) {
 let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    while (sum < n){
    sum += array[i];
    }
    if (sum === n){
      return true}
      else{
        return false}
    }
  
  }
  
  console.log(sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 13))
```

Comment: hace un tiempo salió una pregunta exactamente igual, si buscas un poco la encontrarás

Comment: Revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/248432/146637 ya después solo seria comparar con el valor ingresado. ;)

Comment: La variable `sum` es un acumulador desde el índice `0` hasta el `i` (el último valor antes de superar a `n`). No es lo mismo que la suma de `array[i]+array[j]` dos valores cualesquiera.

Comment: Muchas gracias @AlfredoMaussa. Efectivamente sumaba de a 2 porque el array comenzaba en 2. No podía darme cuenta! :P Necesitaba otra variable para almacenar las sumas. He intentado esto y aparentemente funciona bien. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Es la suma de dos numeros cualesquiera del arreglo, o tambien podria ser 3, 4, etc numeros del arreglo que su suma es igual al numero pasado por parametro?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer esto

```js
const chequearValor = (arr, n) => arr.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0) === n
console.log(chequearValor([2,2,2,2], 8))
console.log(chequearValor([234,2,2,2], 8))
console.log(chequearValor([2,25,2,2], 8))
```

`a y b` son el elemento del array y el acumulador, y lo que se retorna `a + b` es el nuevo acumulador.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
function sumArray(array, n) {
 let sum = 0;
 //solo recorremos el arreglo y vamos sumando
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sum += array[i];
   }
  // una vez sumado comparamos
  // si es igual retorna true 
  // si no lo es retorna false
  return sum ==n
  // tambien podrias hacer esto pero es mas codigo
  /*
  if (sum === n){
    return true
  }
  else{
    return false
  }
  */
  }
  
  console.log(sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 13))
  console.log(sumArray([3,3,3,3,1], 13))
```

hay otras formas de sumar arreglo mas simples:

[Sumar elementos de un Array en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/248429/sumar-elementos-de-un-array-en-javascript/248432#248432)

Answer (score -1):

La solución que encontré: Añadir una variable "contador" e ir incrementando la variable sum.

```js
 function sumArray(array, n) {
 
  let sum = 0;
  let contador = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    while (sum < n){
    sum = sum + array[i];
    contador = sum++
    }
    if (contador === n){
      return true}
      else{
        return false}
    }
  
  }
  
  console.log(sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 13))
```

Answer (score -1):

Una solución muy simple usando el método reduce, que aquí viene de perlas

```
function sumArray(array, n){
return  (array.reduce((ac, valor)=>ac+valor) == n)
}
```

Con el método reduce vamos sumando los valores de la lista a un acumulador inicialmente 0 (por defecto).
La función devuelve el resultado de comparar el valor reducido (el acumulador) con el 2º parámetro.